# Access form input values within jquery validate's submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

How should a given form input be accessed within jQuery validate()'s submitHandler callback?  I have a convoluted solution, but expect there must be a better way.

http://jsfiddle.net/1tzuojpg/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var inputs=$(form).find(':input');
                console.log('inputs',inputs);
                console.log('form',form,$(form),form.elements);
                console.log('this',this, $(this));
                //console.log( this.serializeArray() ); //this is not a jQuery object
                console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
                console.log( $( form ).serializeArray() );
                console.log( inputs.serializeArray() );
                alert(inputs.filter('[name=myName]').val());
            }
        });
  });

<form id='myform' >
   <input type='text' name='myName' value="123" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You have not explained the root problem at all or what you ultimately are trying to achieve.  Typically one uses jQuery's `.serialize()` to get the form's data before submitting.  Otherwise, a single input can be targeted and attached to `.val()` to get its value.

Comment: Why `inputs.filter('[name=myName]').val()` instead of simply `$('[name=myName]').val()`?

Comment: @Sparky  Usually, I use `.serialize()` exactly as you say.  For this time, however, I wish to get the value of a couple form inputs and add them to a table, and them send them to the server upon some other event.

Comment: Then target the input's value directly:  `$('input[name="myName"]').val()`

Comment: @Sparky.  Definitely better than what I was doing.  Thanks!

Comment: Or even `$('[name="myName"]').val()`

Comment: Although `input[name="myName"]` is slightly more specific than `[name="myName"]`, it's personal coding preference I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Target the input's value directly: `$('#myform input[name="myName"]').val()`

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/fz3ed89q/2/

Using the built-in `form` argument:  `$(form).find('input[name="myName"]').val()`

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/fz3ed89q/3/

Comment: I see that your approach doesn't obtain the inputs from the `form` or `this` object.  A concern would be multiple forms with inputs of the same name.  http://jsfiddle.net/fz3ed89q/1/

Comment: @user1032531, just give the selector more specificity.  See edited answer.  BTW- the `$(this)` object is not used within the `submitHandler` since it has no context there, and if you really want to use the `form` argument:  `$(form).find('input[name="myName"]').val()`

Comment: Was about to suggest your second solution as well.  I think it is the best, but I am surprised that super clean solution.  Oh well.  Thanks for your help.